# Create clickable link from file path in data frame to excel

Tags: r, excel

Let's say I have the following data frame and I want to create hyperlink to the filepath is there a way I can do this and export it to excel? Some rows have two hyperlinks.
I want to keep the same format as the output jut add the hyperlinks.
Using R

| File_name | File_path |
| --- | --- |
| b~cat | c:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg |
| b~dog | c:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg |
| NA | NA |
| b~duck | c:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg |
| b~goat; b~horse | c:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg; c:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg |
| NA | NA |
| b~cow | c:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg |

Answer (score 0):

You can add a clickable hyperlink with the following code in R :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/excel_File_1.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File)
sheet <- xlWbk$Sheets(1)
rng <- sheet$Range("B2")
sheet$Hyperlinks()$Add(rng, Address = "D:/Dropbox/excel_File_2.xlsx", TextToDisplay = "Here is my link")
```